# Can I embed CORS anywhere code into my javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, client, cors-anywhere

Can I embed CORS anywhere code into my client side javascript/jquery code rather then using "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" along with my URL. Because many times it gives Application Error and I can't able to access my URL. If I would have local copy of CORS anywhere it would convenient. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can install the reverse-proxy script on your local development machine. See https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/
You will bee needing NodeJS to be running on your machine.
Or if you are in the development stage and need to bypass CORS you can start your chrome browser on Windows with this command line:

```
start .\chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:/Chrome"
```